# New to programming, can't get visual studio 2013 to open include file

Tags: compiler-errors, fatal-error

I'm going through the slow process of learning to code C++, and I've come across a problem that has me completely stumped.

I'm trying to save a custom header from  www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h and get my .cpp file to open it in the directory. I've saved the header in the same directory as my .cpp file already and this is what the code in the VS looks like

```
#include <header1.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "its bumming me out pretty bad\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `#include "header1.h"` See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

Answer (score 4):

first, include should be like this:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

and you can't use cout without including iostream so it finally should looks like :

```
#include "header1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "its bumming me out pretty bad\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation `<..>` tells the compiler you are referring to a standard header, and its full path is known (i.e., it's in VS's default location *or* you manually included that path).

Use double quotes `#include "header1.h"` to refer to the folder where your CPP is stored.